# How to speed up images in this simple jscript slider on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html

```
-------------- JavaScript Code -------------
$('.ppt li:gt(0)').hide();
$('.ppt li:last').addClass('last');
var cur = $('.ppt li:first');

function animate() {
    cur.fadeOut( 1000 );
    if ( cur.attr('class') == 'last' )
        cur = $('.ppt li:first');
    else
        cur = cur.next();
    cur.fadeIn( 1000 );
}


$(function() {
    setInterval( "animate()", 6000 );

} );
---------------- The End of JScript Code ---------
```

I hate JScript, please help!

```
------------------HTML Code ------------------------
<div id="slider">
<ul class="ppt">
    <li><img src="../Slider/Slika_1.jpg" alt="Projman 1"></img></li>
    <li><img src="../Slider/Slika_2.jpg" alt="Projman 2"></img></li>
    <li><img src="../Slider/Slika_3.jpg" alt="Projman 3"></img></li>
    <li><img src="../Slider/Slika_4.jpg" alt="Projman 4"></img></li>
    <li><img src="../Slider/Slika_5.jpg" alt="Projman 5"></img></li>
    <li><img src="../Slider/Slika_6.jpg" alt="Projman 6"></img></li>
</ul>
</div>

-------------------The End of HTML Code ----------------
```

I just need to make a hover effect that set an interval on 1000 when mouse over and bact to normal when mouse out, anyone? Help! Greetings!

Comment: Why are there `<br />` tags in your JS?

Comment: im sorry bro, half hour i spent formatting the code, this is my first time here on stack overflow, i realy need help. tommorow i must deliver site one managment companie, im dead

Comment: Firstly - you need to remove the quotes around the `animate()` function.

Comment: thank you by the way, but thats not the problem my brother..slider work i just need to speed up imgs on mouseover (hover) for let say from 6000 to 1000, i just need simple hover efect, just like in css, but here with javascript. :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to happen when you hover. At the moment you're just calling animate() every 6 seconds. If you want that to happen faster just change the interval to 1000.

Comment: first of all, thank you my brothers :)..my client want when user put his cursor on slider, then imgs changing faster and when he move cursor its normal again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the accepted answer is not working correctly.

- The `setInterval` calls should use `animate` as a parameter, not `animate()`.
- You shouldn't put the mouse handling on the images, because when the
  image hides, it counts as a `mouseleave`, so the next image will be slow again, despite the mouse pointer is hovering the slider.
- You also need to clear the previoulsy scheduled interval, when you set a new interval.
- When you switch to 1000ms interval, you need to lower the fadein-fadeout intervals as well, so they fit in that 1000ms.

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZLLD/1/). It's longer, but it addresses these problems.

And here is a [sliding variant](http://jsfiddle.net/gZLLD/2/).

Comment: bro this works perfect but not when i implement code?? i dont understand?

Comment: Sorry man - I was working within your code sample - not completely changing it.  I can quickly modify my sample to work better.

Comment: this version work perfect but here in this fiddle but not here in my code, im confused

Comment: You should put the full code inside the jquery ready handler `(function() {...});` at the bottom. (The fiddle is setup to do that automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/gyrH9/) for you to look at.

Jquery uses a `.hover()` function to allow you to pause and restart on the hover event.

```
$('.ppt li:gt(0)').hide();
$('.ppt li:last').addClass('last');
var cur = $('.ppt li:first');
var nextSpeed = 6000;
var fadeSpeed = 1000;

function animate() {
    cur.fadeOut( fadeSpeed );
    if ( cur.attr('class') == 'last' )
        cur = $('.ppt li:first');
    else
        cur = cur.next();
    cur.fadeIn( fadeSpeed );
    timer = setTimeout(animate, nextSpeed);
}


$('#slider').hover(
    function() {
            if (nextSpeed != 1000) {
            if (timer) { 
                clearTimeout(timer); 
            }
            nextSpeed = 1000;
            fadeSpeed = 200;
            animate();
        }
    }, function() {
            nextSpeed = 6000;
            fadeSpeed = 1000;
    }
);

$(function() {
    animate();
} );
```

This should get you where you need to be.

**Edit**
Updated fiddle to account for the issues stated.  Hover is still the appropriate choice. Sorry I didn't spend much time the first go - should work better now.

*Side Note* - there are plugins that do this much better - may want to investigate those.

Comment: CSS looks terrible - but you didn't provide that, so I'm not able to reproduce exactly what you have.

Comment: i hope it will work bro, thank you so much, sorry on my bad english im serbian son, i respect that my brother, like was 2pac said keep ya head up :)

Comment: do i need some special jquery or what cause it doesn work, it must be because of a jqure, i use 1.10.2?

Comment: You must have another issue then, outside of this code. Check where jquery is loaded, check the console for errors etc.